# Solve : $2^{x}+2^{y}=12 ; x+y=5, x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: solution-verification, problem-solving

How to solve $2^{x}+2^{y}=12 ; x+y=5, x,y\in \mathbb{R}$?

Attempt:
$2^{x}+2^{y}=12\implies 2^{5-y}+2^y=12\implies 2^y=4,8\implies y=2,3$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you please show us what you have tried so we can better understand what it is that you don't understand?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $2^y$ or $2^x$

Comment: While you have gotten the right answer, I'm pretty sure the 2nd equation in your attempt should be $2^{5-y}+2^y=12$ due to solving for $y$ in the 2nd equation in the problem.

Answer (score 3):

$$2^x+2^y=2^{5-y}+2^y=\frac{2^5}{2^y}+2^y=12 $$

$$2^5+2^{2y}=12\cdot2^y \Longleftrightarrow 2^{2y}-12\cdot2^y+2^5=0 $$

$$2^{2y}-12\cdot2^y+2^5=(2^y-2^3)(2^y-2^2) = 0$$

$$2^y=2^3\Longleftrightarrow y=3 $$

$$2^y=2^2 \Longleftrightarrow y=2 $$